# Can one show that $\int_\gamma F'(z)dz=F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$ without assuming that $f$ is analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

The following appeared as a Complex Analysis homework problem.

> Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ be a regular curve and let $F\in C^1(\mathbb{C})$. Show that $\int_\gamma F'(z)dz=F(\gamma(b))-F(\gamma(a))$.

Now, if we add the extra condition that $F$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$, I see that the proof is pretty straightforward and can be solved by writing $F=u+iv$ and using chain rule.

But without the assumption that $F$ is analytic, I don't think it can be proven. Am I right?

Comment: Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to $\phi'$ where $\phi(t) = F(\gamma(t)))$. Nothing really complex here :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Hi Joe!  Happy New Year (Is one allowed to say that in mid-February?).  I hope that the MSE moderators don't punish you for that last part of your comment.

Comment: @MarkViola: :-). Many happy returns! Wasn't trying to be punny :-).

Comment: Well be careful, else you'll be sent to a punitentiary.

Comment: The question is this: What do you mean by $F'(z)$ if $F$ is not analytic (complex differentiable)?

Comment: The notation suggests $F$ is complex differentiable at each $\gamma(t)$ (thus $(F(\gamma(t))' = F'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)$) it doesn't imply $F$ is holomorphic or analytic. If $F'(\gamma(t)) $ is (piecewise) continuous then this is just the FTC. Otherwise $F(\gamma(t))$ continuous implies $F'(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t)$ is $L^1_{loc}$ so it is the Lebesgue version of FTC

Comment: You haven't given us all the hypotheses. Like Ted Shifren wrote, what does $F'(z)$ even mean?

Comment: @MarkViola: I'd understand $C^1(\mathbb{C})$ to imply *real* differentiability, i.e. the function is continuously differentiable as a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  In other words, the real and imaginary parts of $f$ have continuous partial derivatives. This does not imply that it is entire (consider $f(z) = |z|^2$).

Comment: @MarkViola Certainly not without further information. $f\in C^1$ means, usually, that  $\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y$ exist everywhere and each is a continuous function.

Comment: I thought that $C^1$ means continuously differentiable (i.e., $f'(z)$ is continuous).

Comment: @NateEldredge I interpreted $C^1$ to mean continuously differentiable (i.e., $f'(z)$ is continuous).

Comment: @MarkViola $C^1$ is rarely meant to convey differentiability in the complex sense; the notation is meant to to convey differentiability in the real sense.

Comment: @zhw. That is interesting as I would have interpreted $C^1(\mathbb{C})$ to mean continuously differentiable on the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the definition of $C^1$.

- Some complex analysis books (like James Ward Brown) define a complex function $f=u+iv$ to be $C^1$ if the partial derivatives $u_x,u_y,v_x,v_y$ exist and are continuous.
- Other complex analysis books give a stronger definition of $C^1$, which includes the condition that $f'$ exists and is continuous.

For solving OP's problem, it seems natural to use the 2nd definition of $C^1$.